# A light/web novel about a person reincarnated as the youngest child in a noble family, who later learns magic from a zombie magician

Tags: hachinan

The main character of the story is a boy born into a noble family that rules the surrounding farming lands but is actually rather poor. He has many big brothers, and therefore he has no hopes of becoming the successor of the family, but he doesn't have any intention of doing so anyway. His father also has an affair with the village head's daughter.

No one pays attention to him or expects anything from him, except for one of his big brothers. Magicians are rare in the world, but his father does have some magic books, even though he cannot use magic himself. It turns out the boy has a great talent for magic and learns very quickly. He also visits the woods behind the estate to train his magic and hunt for game. Because the woods are dangerous, people generally don't enter leisurely, and since the population is desperately needed for farming, there are not many hunters. When he brings back animals he hunted, he is greatly praised for adding meat to their family's fare, which is usually made of unappetizing gruel.

One day, he meets a zombie in the woods, who turns out to be a great magician who died but cannot leave because of his wish to find a disciple. In a short time, the boy learns his new master's magic and also receives his mana capacity. His master grants him his magic storage ring, which among many other items, also includes rations that could feed an army for months. The boy grants his master a peaceful death with his newly learnt magic.

It slowly becomes known that this young master can use magic, and the village head approaches him to usurp his oldest brother's claim to the title of the head of the house. The boy, however, does not wish for conflict nor is he interested in the position.

When his oldest brother marries, all of his big brothers are forced to leave the house, since they have come of age and need to find their own path in the world. The boy gets to stay a few more years because he is still too young. His mastery of magic allows him to fly, and thus he can visit other cities. In the city, he pretends to be a young boy from a neighboring village who came to sell game his father hunted.

When he becomes a bit older, the boy leaves his home to enroll in an adventurer's school. In order not to strain his finances, he applies for scholarship and passes the test with flying colors. He forms a team with 1 other boy and 2 girls.

As a representative of his house, he is invited to attend a party of the reigning local noble. It turns out that they were interested in him because they found out about his connection with his master. His master was a genius magician among their ranks, who was sent to battle but perished and ended up wandering around as a zombie. The noble asks for the battle rations back and the boy returns them. In exchange, they hand over his master's bank account and house.

I think that the description of this novel says that it contains a lot of economic topics. If I recall correctly, the main character is also a reincarnated person from another world. The novel is in the mangaupdates.com database, but I cannot find it. Please help if you know it, thanks!

Comment: that sounds really interesting, hope you find it

Answer (score 3):

I found it. It's [**Hachinan tte, Sore wa Nai Deshou!**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=121027)

Synopsis from mangaupdates:

> Ichinomiya Shingo, a young 25 years old, single, worker of firm company while thinking of tomorrow' busy working day goes to sleep. However the moment he woke up, it's a room unknown to him. He then learn that he is inside a 6 years-old boy and is taking over his mind. He then learn a lot from the memories of the said boy: he was born as the youngest child (8th son and 10th child) of poor noble family living in back country. Having no administrative skill, he can't do anything to manage the vast land his family has.
>
> Fortunately, he is blessed with a very rare talent, talent of magic. Unfortunately, while his talent could bring prosperity to his family, in his situation it only brought disaster. Yes, this is the story of the boy, Wendelin Von Benno Baumeister, opening his own path in a harsh world.